# Is this player offside?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

Considering all opposing players are on the left side of the pitch, is player 22 offside ?
I drew this on paint so please pardon the laziness.
Might seem odd as a question but all opposing players are on my side (left side) of the pitch does that not free the player 22 ?

[image]

Comment: Hopefully the linked question answers this for you; if not, could you edit your question to explain why you think 22 might possibly _not_ be offside?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Because every opposing player is on my side (left side) of the pitch does that not count ?

Comment: This one might be relevant: https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/18401/15589

Comment: It's still not clear to me what exactly the question is, but either way it is a duplicate. If the black player is in their own half, the other Q&A already takes care of it. If the black player is in their opponent's half, the other Q&A takes care of it.

Comment: @Nij All I'm asking is if all red players (except GK) are in the blacks' side of the pitch and One black player is on the reds' side of the pitch, is that one black player offside ?

Comment: Pretty simple: if it's not in the Laws it doesn't exist.